# Any simpler expression for$\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}{k\big(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\big)}}{n\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, summation, self-learning

Is there any simpler form for the following expression:

$$
\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}{k\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\right)}}{n\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}$$

Because I have to compute this expression for $n=100$, and without using any computing packages, doing this would be really tedious and painful.

If anybody knows how to simplify the expression (or simple methods to compute it by hand), I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you need an accurate answer for $n=100$? Otherwise, $\sum (-1)^i/i!$ approximates $1/e$.

Comment: note your numerator is just a product of 2 sums, the first is arithmetic series $\sum_k k$ and the second is close to $1/e$, so the second factor will roughly cancel the sum in the denominator...

Comment: Given the sum over k part, taking $n$ large will be divergent so probably something else is in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A_n=\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}{k\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\right)}}{n\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!} }{n\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}} \sum_{k=2}^{n-2}k=\frac{1}{2} (n-3) n\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!} }{n\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}} $$ Now $$\sum_{i=0}^{p}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\frac{\Gamma (p+1,-1)}{e\,\Gamma (p+1)}$$ where appear the complete and incomplete gamma functions. Replacing the values of $p$, we then get $$A_n=\frac{(n-3) \Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (n-1,-1)}{2 \Gamma (n-1) \Gamma (n+1,-1)}=\frac{1}{2} (n-3) (n-1) n\,\frac{\Gamma (n-1,-1)}{\Gamma (n+1,-1)}$$ which can also be written as $$A_n=\frac{1}{2} (n-3) (n-1) n\,\frac{!(n-2)}{!n}$$ where appears the [subfactorial function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html) which gives the number of permutations of $n$ objects that leave no object fixed.

If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), you will notice that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {!n \over n!} = {1 \over e} $$ . So, for large values of $n$ , $$A_n\approx \frac{1}{2} (n-3) (n-1) n\,\frac{(n-2)!}{e}\,\frac e {n!}= \frac{1}{2} (n-3)$$

For example, for $n=10$, the exact value is $\frac{519155}{148329}\approx 3.5000236$ for an approximation of $3.5$; for $n=100$, the  values differ by $1.4\times 10^{-154}$; for $n=1000$, the  values differ by $3.4\times 10^{-2562}$. I suppose that you can stay with this good (and may be surprising) approximation.

**Edit**

If you look [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Subfactorial/06/02/0001/), you will notice the approximation $$!z=\sqrt{2 \pi } \,e^{-(z+1)}\, z^{z+\frac{1}{2}} \left(1+\frac{1}{12 z}+\frac{1}{288 z^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)+\cdots\right)
  $$ Using it for the estimation of $\frac{!(n-2)}{!n}$ we get $$\frac{!(n-2)}{!n}=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ which, continuing the expansions, finally makes $$A_n=\frac {n-3}2+\frac{139}{17280 \,n^3}+\frac{1673}{207360\, n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Comment: Very nice! Isn't the $n^{-3}$ term surprising (large), though? Compare with $n=10,100$ & $1000$ above.

Comment: @bgins. Yes, I noticed. It is quite surprising, isn't it ? I suppose that more terms would be required for the expansion of $!z$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k=\frac 1 2 (n-1)(n-2)$$

Then we write:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}-[\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} +\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}]$$

Then you can write it as:

$$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2n} - \frac{\frac 1 2 (n-1)(n-2)[\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} +\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}]}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}$$

You are only left with one summation.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your numerator doesn't depend on $k$ so you could evaluate each part separately.

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}=\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$$

The other parts can then be written in terms of the $\Gamma$ function (both normal form and incomplete form):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\frac{\Gamma_{-1}(n-1)}{e\cdot\Gamma(n-1)}$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\frac{\Gamma_{-1}(n+1)}{e\cdot\Gamma(n+1)}$$

where $\Gamma(n)$ is the regular [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and $\Gamma_{-1}(n)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) (evaluated with $x=-1)$

As $n$ is an integer you can replace $\Gamma(n)$ with $(n+1)!$ but I'm not sure of a similar simplification for $\Gamma_{-1}(n)$.

So the entire thing could be rewritten as:

$$\frac{(n-3)(n+2)!\cdot\Gamma_{-1}(n-1)}{2\cdot n!\cdot\Gamma_{-1}(n+1)}$$

$$=\frac{(n-3)(n+2)(n+1)\cdot\Gamma_{-1}(n-1)}{2\cdot\Gamma_{-1}(n+1)}$$

Comment: $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: @bgins I used that. Do you know of a simplification for the incomplete Gamma function?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an exact or approximate answer? If approximate, how accurate (how many places)?

The Taylor polynomial $T_n(x)$ for $f(x)=e^x$ about $0$ of degree $n$ is
$$T_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!},$$
and the Mean Value Theorem (or [explicit Lagrange form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)) for the remainder $R_n(x)=f(x)-T_n(x)$ is that there exists some $\xi_n$ between $0$ and $x$ so that
$$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_n)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}.$$
This gives us a strong bound on the difference of the sums you have from $e^{-1}$:
$$R_n(-1)=e^{-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}e^{\xi_n}}{(n+1)!}\qquad\text{for some}\quad\xi_n\in(-1,0).$$
Note that $e^{\xi_n}<1$ for each $n$, and replacing $\xi_n$ by 0 gives us an upper bound on $|R_n(-1)|$:
$$|R_n(-1)|<\frac1{(n+1)!}.$$
So in particular, there exist constants $\xi_{n-2},\xi_{n}\in(0,1)$ (probably very close to $-1$) so that your expression (say $E_n$) is
$$\begin{align}
E_n
&=\frac{\left(\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}k\right)
 \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
 \right)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}
\\&=\frac1n\cdot\left(\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}2-1\right)
 \cdot\frac{T_{n-2}(-1)}{T_{n}(-1)}
\\&=\frac{n-3}2\cdot\frac{e^{-1}-R_{n-2}(-1)}{e^{-1}-R_{n}(-1)}
\\&=\frac{n-3}2\cdot\frac{
 e^{-1}-\frac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{\xi_{n-2}}}{(n-1)!}
 }{e^{-1}-\frac{(-1)^{n+1}e^{\xi_n}}{(n+1)!}}
\end{align}$$
and, for $n=100$,
$$\begin{align}
E_{100}
&=\frac{97}2\cdot\frac{
 e^{-1}+{e^{\xi_{98}}}/{99!} }{
e^{-1}+{e^{\xi_{100}}}/{101!} }
\\&\approx\frac{97}2\cdot\frac{e^{-1}+1/99!}{e^{-1}+1/101!}\\&=
\frac{97}2\left(1+\frac{e}{99!}\left(1-\frac1{100\cdot101}\right)\right).
\end{align}$$
This is certainly quite close to $\frac{97}2$; you could use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to estimate that $100!\approx9.3\times10^{157}$, so $E_{100}$ should be just a fraction of this larger than $\frac{97}2$, and $48.5$ should be accurate to over $150$ decimal places.

Comment: Funny problem, isn't it ? Even for $n=5$ the approximation is not bad !!